# Jquery how do I add +1 to a number in a table

Tags: jquery

So I am generating a table with php/mysql, and in this table are numbers in rows. I have a button that when clicked, adds +1 to this number value **in the MySQL database**. The problem is, I have to refresh the page for the new number to show up in the table.

I am attempting to show the new number immediatly through a function on the **success** of the jquery button click event.  So essentially I need to identify the HTML generated number in the table, then add +1 to it.

The problem is, the table is generated with a **while** function in php, so each row gets its own ID on the fly.

Hope this all makes sense.

Here is my Jquery code so far.

```
   $('.upArrow').click(function(){
   //this is finding the uparrow button that adds +1
   var row = $(this).attr('rowid');

    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "upArrow.php?id="+row,
    cache: false,
    async: false,
    success: function(result){
    //this is tricky part, how do I select the displayed number part of the
    // table, then Add 1?

    },
    error: function(result){
        alert('Error, please try again.');
    }
    });
});
```

Edit: Here is a piece of my HTML table:

```
    <td id="musicDisplay" colspan="2">

    <div id="newUpArrow">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class = "upArrow"
        rowid="' . $row['id'] . '"><img src="../Img/upArrow.gif"/>
            </a> </div>

     <!--Here is the number I want to change.-->
    <div>'. $row['points'] . '</div>
 </td>
```

Comment: I was first just reading *Jquery how do I add +1 to a number* and thought OMG.... ;) Please post your HTML too. You also should not use a GET request for this. It is ok with Ajax, but if someone just types it in the address bar and is going through the history etc, the values might get increased involuntarily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory, you'll want to *set the context* of your ajax request to the element containing the text you want. Then on success, you would increase the number in that context.

```
$.ajax({
    /* everything else as before */
    context: $('selector for element containing number to increase'),
    success: function(result) {
        $(this).html(parseInt($(this).html(), 10) + 1);
    }
});
```

***This assumes that the content of the context element will always be a single integer***

If you need to select a cell by it's column and row, you could do the following:

```
    var column = 1;
    var row = 1;

    var $cell = $('table tr:eq(' + row + ') td:eq(' + column + ')');

    $cell.html(parseInt($cell.html(), 10) + 1);
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xixionia/4HLp9/

Although, you would need to change "table" to a table's id, otherwise you'll end up selecting all of the cells from *every* table at that row in and column.

**Note:** Having seen your html, we would be able to provide a much more detailed description of how to select the desired cell.

Comment: If you use `parseInt`, don't forget to pass the correct radix as second parameter (`10` for decimal values). If the whole text is a number, then `+$cell.html()` is a faster way to convert the string to a number.

Comment: Thanks, Felix... I started to edit that, but then lost the page and forgot. Sorry :) Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

How many rows do you have? It might make sense just to re-generate the table from the AJAX call and reload the html on it's way back.